# How can I prevent row duplicates in Django when no field is unique?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, duplicates

Upon saving an object, is there a simple way to prevent duplication when the combination of all the fields together have the same data?

The **unique=True** parameter doesn't seem to help here, because individually any of the data could be duplicated, but never all of them at the same time.

If statement with several and conditions does not seem to me like a smart way so I'm looking for a better approach. Does Django provide it? All I could find was related to one field or other being duplicated.

**views.py**

```
def collect(request):
    # Requests data from the API
    response = requests.get('url')
    data = json.loads(response.text)

# Filters wanted data from JSON and saves on the DB
    for key in data:
        if Item.objects.filter(model=key['properties']['model']).exists() == True and Item.objects.filter(number=key['properties']['number']).exists() and Item.objects.filter(model=key['properties']['city']).exists() == True and Item.objects.filter(number=key['properties']['number']).exists() and Item.objects.filter(model=key['properties']['state']).exists() == True:
            continue
        else:
            a = Item()
            a.model = key['properties']['model']
            a.number = key['properties']['number']
            a.timestamp = dateparse.parse_datetime(key['properties']['data_hora_gmt'])
            a.city = key['properties']['city']
            a.state = key['properties']['state']
            a.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

**models.py:**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    model = models.TextField()
    number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    city = models.TextField()
    state = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Can you share the full view?

Comment: I edited to provide more of it but I can't post the complete code. I hope it is enough to get a glimpse of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unique_together` so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
  field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('field1', 'field2',)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for.
Worth to mention that Django docs are suggesting they might deprecate it in the future and we should use UniqueConstraint instead. I'll check it out as well.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint